# Angular 2 firebase dynamic url links

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Can I make dynamic url links with firebase ? For example :

- 1.User logins
- 2.Users posts some projects ( name, description, photos)
- 3.Users goes into the project with a dynamic link
- 4.That link should be www.app.com/postID
- 5.Only the post on which was clicked data would be visible (this.post.data)
- 6.If user clicks on another, it gives only that post data.

Is it even possible with firebase? Maby I need to use HTTPClient ?